# Parse XML node by node and check for leaf node

Tags: java, xml

I used XPath expression `//*[count(./*) = 0]` to find the leaf nodes in an XML. But instead of using the expression, I wanted to parse the XML, node by node and check if it is a leaf node or not. How can I accomplish this? My XML is a dynamic one.

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Java API for XML Processing (JAXP)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/), in particular pay attention to the section on [Document Object Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/index.html)

Comment: This could be written either as a DOM or SAX program. Which is better depends on what one intends to do with the leaf nodes once they're found. I agree that the answer's a bit more obvious with the DOM -- if a node has no children it's a leaf -- whereas with SAX you need to maintain a bit of state information to track whether an element was empty when it ends, but it shouldn't be difficult either way.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following java code you can parse the xml and use docEle.hasChildNodes() to check it a leaf node or not.

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document dom = db.parse("file.xml");
    Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();

    NodeList nl = docEle.getChildNodes();
    if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            if (nl.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                  Element el = (Element) nl.item(i);
                  el.getTextContent().trim();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: U don't need value right. U need to check whether it is a child node or not. if you need use this el.getTextContent().trim();